# How to set UISegmentedControls programmatically with values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to read from an XML document which is alreay working. But now I have to write UISegmentedcontrols with the values out of that XML. The values that are parsed are in this format:

```
<wcqAnswerValues>slecht;matig;voldoende;goed</wcqAnswerValues>
```

Which are four values, separated by the semicolon. So the UISegmentedControl needs to get four segments. The first two segments need to have actions on them. How do I split those four values and put them into an UISegmentedControl?

If the first two values are selected, a textfield needs to pop out. How can I do this?

```
static CGFloat y1 = 100.0f;
do {
    if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"wcqAnswerValues"]) {
        UISegmentedControl *answer = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, y1, 250, 50)];

        answer.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

        [scrollView addSubview:answer];

        [formulierText removeFromSuperview];

        [answer release];
        y1 += 50.0f;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **componentsSeperatedByString:** method to split a string into an array. And use **addTarget:action:forControlEvents:** method to handle segment selection action.

```
NSString *segmentItemsStr = @"slecht;matig;voldoende;goed";
NSArray *segmentItemsArray = [segmentsStr componentsSeperatedByString:@";"];
UISegmentedControl *answer = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentItemsArray]; 
[answer addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
...
```

The **someMethod:** method looks like this.

```
- (void)someMethod:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 || sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

        // Code to pop up the text field
    }
}
```